# CordovaError: Invalid Plugin! ..\hello needs a valid package.json

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

I am trying to develop a custom plugin in Cordova. Problem is that Cordova does not recognize the JSON file. [image: Click here to see image]

my json file:

```
{
  "name": "hello",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "description": "show hello cordova",
  "cordova": {
    "id": "cordova-plugin-hello",
    "platforms": []
  },
  "keywords": [
    "ecosystem:cordova"
  ],
  "author": "shubham",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

my plugin.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<plugin id="cordova-plugin-hello" version="0.1.1" xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"><name>hello</name><js-module name="hello" src="www/hello.js"><clobbers target="cordova.plugins" /></js-module>
```

Thank you for your help and for your time.

Answer (score 5):

For adding a custom Cordova plugin, you can use [Plugman](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugman).

You can **Install Plugman globally** using the command

```
npm install -g plugman
```

Then Navigate to the folder where you want to create your plugin.

**Create the initial code** of our plugin using the following command

```
plugman create --name YourPluginName --plugin_id cordova-plugin-YourPluginName --plugin_version 0.0.1
```

Add **Android platform** to the plugin using command

```
plugman platform add --platform_name android
```

Now, for **creating package.json file** in your current directory, in the plugin based on values from plugin.xml, use the command

```
plugman createpackagejson -- or npm init
```

Now for installing the plugin in our existing Cordova project for Android using command

```
plugman install --platform android --project platforms/android --plugin ../YourPluginName/
```

reference  [visit here](https://github.com/RootSoft/Create-a-custom-Cordova-plugin).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20822277)

Comment: Thanks @MatheusLacerda